# java cast and Forms 11g

Tags: java, excel, oracleforms

I've found a java code which read an excel file. I imported it into Forms11g to use it for the same purpose but I couldn't compile it due to casting errors in lines
`HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();` and `HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();`

- The java code works good of course.
- The java code, into Forms, works good when I make (HSSFROW) and (HSSFCell) in comment!!

Here's the java code :

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;

public class ExcelReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("1.xls"));

            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(input);
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            System.out.print("sheet " + sheet.getSheetName());

            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                System.out.println("\n");

                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                while (cells.hasNext()) {

                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();

                    if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC == cell.getCellType()) {
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + " ");
                    } else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING == cell.getCellType()) {
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+ " ");
                    } else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN == cell.getCellType()) {
                        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + " ");
                    } else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK == cell.getCellType()) {
                        System.out.print("BLANK ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("Unknown cell type");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Forms-Java code :

```
DECLARE
     raisedexception ora_java.jobject;
      input    ora_java.jobject; --InputStream
      fs       ora_java.jobject; --poifsfilesystem
      wb       ora_java.jobject; --hssfworkbook
      sheet    ora_java.jobject; --HSSFSheet
      rows     ora_java.jobject; --Iterator
      ROW      ora_java.jobject; --HSSFRow
      cells    ora_java.jobject; --Iterator
      cell     ora_java.jobject; --HSSFCell
      i        INTEGER := 0;
      num_val  NUMBER;
      date_val DATE;
      char_val VARCHAR2(100);
      bool_val BOOLEAN;
    BEGIN
      input := bufferedinputstream.new(fileinputstream.new(:b_param.fichier));

      fs    := poifsfilesystem.new(input);
      wb    := hssfworkbook.new_0(fs);
      sheet := hssfworkbook.getsheetat(wb, 0);

      go_block('b_file_content');
      rows := hssfsheet.rowiterator(sheet);
      WHILE (iterator.hasnext(rows)) LOOP
        i   := 0;
        ROW :=  /*(HSSFRow)*/
         iterator.next(rows);

        cells := hssfrow.celliterator(ROW);
        WHILE (iterator.hasnext(cells)) LOOP

          i := i + 1;

          cell :=  /*(HSSFCell)*/
           iterator.next(cells);

          IF (hssfcell.cell_type_numeric = hssfcell.getcelltype(cell)) THEN
            copy(hssfcell.getnumericcellvalue(cell),
                 ':b_file_content.cell' || i);
          ELSIF (hssfcell.cell_type_string = hssfcell.getcelltype(cell)) THEN
            copy(hssfcell.getstringcellvalue(cell),
                 ':b_file_content.cell' || i);
          ELSIF (hssfcell.cell_type_blank = hssfcell.getcelltype(cell)) THEN
            copy('BLANK', ':b_file_content.cell' || i);
          ELSE
            copy('Unknown type', ':b_file_content.cell' || i);
          END IF;

        END LOOP;

        next_record;
      END LOOP;

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN ora_java.java_error THEN
        message('pb_trait java_error ' || ora_java.last_error);
      WHEN ora_java.exception_thrown THEN
        raisedexception := exception_.new(ora_java.last_exception);
        message('pb_trait exception_thrown ' ||
                exception_.tostring(raisedexception));
    END;
```

How could I fix it please?

Regards.

Comment: Is it throwing one of the exceptions seen in the forms code, or is it a java-based casting error? if it is a java-based casting error I would suggest using a different iterator like: `BufferedReader`.

Comment: It would be a forms error. The java code works good in Netbeans IDE. Here is the error `Error 103: symbol "ITERATOR" met in place of one of the following symbols : * & = - + ; <> or in is mod reminder...`.     How can I use `BufferReader` in this case?

Comment: I workarounded that problem by creating other java method witch returns an arraylist of **HSSFRow** and other one witch returns **HSSFCell**. After importing them into **Forms11g**, I imported the java **ArrayList** as well and used it for reading Excel file data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Apache POI, so I am not absolutely certain how to fix this; however after searching I found that the Row and Cell Iterators should be declared in the fashion of a list e.g. 
 
`Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();` 
 
Hopefully you can derive something from this . . . 
From what I have seen declaring the Iterators with <> is what will fix your problem. If I could take a guess, it would be because it needs to store multiple pieces of information, and it doesn't have a built in type for that.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The java code works good but not the plsql one which contains the java packages!!!

Comment: I workarounded that problem by creating other java method witch returns an arraylist of **HSSFRow** and other one witch returns **HSSFCell**. After importing them into **Forms11g**, I imported the java **ArrayList** as well and used it for reading Excel file data.

Comment: That's Good Glad You Figured It Out :). I see how that did too, however; like I said, I am not familiar with Apache or Forms11g, so there was no way I could have recommended doing that.